# How to create ByteBuffer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm creating CSRF token at iOS end, in server side they have done using md5 hash, while creating this md5 hash in server side they have used ByteBuffer of 16 size and set random data, in same way how we can do in iOS with allocation of size 16 and set random data as mentioned in code **(0, Math.random()) and (8, Math.random())**? Here is the sample code of server side.

`ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
 bb.putDouble(0, Math.random());
 bb.putDouble(8, Math.random());
 String input = Hex.encodeHexString(bb.array());`

Answer (score 0):

Byte in iOS Swift is an UInt8 object. So, your byte array is

```
var byteArray [UInt8] = []
// and you can append like
let byte : UInt8 = 10
byteArray.append(byte)
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**
This way, you can provide the size

```
var byteArray: [UInt8] = [UInt8](repeatElement(0, count: 2))
// and you can append like
let byte1 : UInt8 = 10
byteArray[0] = byte1
let byte2 : UInt8 = 10
byteArray[1] = byte2
print(byteArray)
```

Comment: How to do same of allocate with size ?